# Does this linq OrderBy method actually sort anything?

Tags: c#, linq

I ran into the following piece below.  Does it actually sort items in the `location` collection?  In this case, does `OrderBy` operate on the data returned by `AddRange`?

```
var locations = new List<Location>();
locations.AddRange(propertyStreets
                       .Select(street => new Location 
                       {
                           Name = street.Source.FullStreetName,
                           Type = "Address",
                           ItemType = ItemType.StreetName,
                           City = street.Source.City,
                           State = street.Source.State,
                           SortOrder = GetAddressSortOrder(street, new[] { parsedAddress })
                       })
                       .OrderBy(loc => loc));
```

Comment: @DavidG So I can simply remove `.OrderBy(loc => loc)` and it won't change a thing?

Comment: Oh hang on, I misread the code. The `OrderBy` here does order the results of the `Select` before adding them to `locations`

Comment: @AngryHacker, because the `OrderBy()` is called on the sequence being passed to `AddRange()`, if you were to remove the `OrderBy()` call, it will potentially change the order in which your new `Location` objects are being added to the `locations` collection. So I'd say you can remove it if and only if the order in which items are stored in that collection is not relevant.

Comment: @DavidG yeah I just reformatted the question to make it easier to read

Comment: No. It works on the data returned by `propertyStreets.Select()`. When you do the `AddRange()` the data is reordered somewhere else (in a private space created by `OrderBy`) and then added to `locations`. Then the private space of `OrderBy` isn't referenced by anyone else and the GC frees it.

Comment: If you're observing the OrderBy not ordering your items, you likely don't have an implementation of `IComparable<Location>` on your Location class.

Comment: It does seem a little peculiar though to have a part of the locations list ordered.

Comment: @JonathonChase That is true. It doesn't.  The reason I am investigating this is that very cccasionally, I get `At least one object must implement IComparable` error.  Which is odd since most of the time I am not getting that error.

Comment: @DavidG If not all the elements are comparable (because the comparer is incorrectly done) then it can happen. Or perhaps the comparator isn't transitive... Normally a < b and b < c means a < c... But an incorrectly done comparator could do anything.

Comment: Questions of the form "what does this code do?" can be answered by running the code. When you ran the code, what happened? Whatever happened, **that's what it does**, and now you know the answer to the question "what does this code do?"

Comment: @EricLippert This snipped is a simplified form of what exists in a legacy app and is so deep within the code and requires so much setup, that's it's difficult to run it in a dev environment.

Comment: You can write `var xs = new List<int>();
xs.AddRange(new[] { 3, 1, 2}.OrderBy(x=>x));` pretty fast, and then you would know the answer.

Comment: Also, the question is a bit incoherent. You say does it operate on the data *returned by addrange*, but addrange does not return anything, and the orderby is called before addrange runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it actually sort items in the location collection?

It does based on following:

The `OrderBy` creates a `OrderedEnumerable` internally based on the expression supplied. In the question `OrderBy(loc => loc)` is using the object itself instead of any property so default compare will be used. Same comparer that is used to compare two objects with `.Equals()` method. Not much of meaningful sort in this case.

> In this case, does OrderBy operate on the data returned by AddRange?

`AddRange` doesn't return anything. The `OrderBy` is applied on projection of collection you are passing in the `AddRange` method means it is getting sorted items based on sort expression.

Comment: Starting in 2022, the pattern `.OrderBy(loc => loc)` can now be written `.Order()` in Linq.